# Triangle inequality for a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose we have a circle centered around $(0,1)$ with radius $1$ i.e the circle described by $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$. Now we construct a point on this circle corresponding to a real number by drawing a straight line ($y=kx+2$) from the point $(0,2)$ on the circle to the $x$ axis in the real plane and say that the point where the line intersects the circle is the new point for the point at which  the line intersects the real line.

Example : suppose we have the point $(2,0)$ then the straight line passing trough the top of the circle $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ is the line $y=-x+2$ which intersects the circle a second time at the point $(1,1)$. Thus we assign the point $(2,0)$ (or simply the number $2$) to be $(1,1)$. (See below an image of two such lines)

More generally if we wish to find the intersection for a number $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ we find ( by plugging the formula for a straight line into the circle) an intersection point at 
$$x=\frac{4t}{4+t^2} \quad y=\frac{-2}{t}\left(\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)+2$$

Now my reason for this is that I wish to define a metric d  as the (positive) arc-length between the points projected onto the circle. I have checked that one  formula for finding the arc length is $"arc-length"= (angle) \times radius$

So using the cosine-formula $$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$$
with the angle A centered at the middle of the circle and a, b and c corresponds to the sides of the triangle with vertices at the middle, and at two points of the circle.
(see picture below for an explanation)
So , to obtain the angle $A$ between two points,
we take two points $s$ and $t$ on the real line and then using the distance formula we take their corresponding point on the circle as obtained above to obtain $a$
$$\begin{align*}a & =\sqrt{\left(\frac{4s}{4+s^2}-\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-2}{s}\left(\frac{4s}{4+s^2}\right)+2-\left(\frac{-2}{t}\left(\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)+2\right)\right)^2}\\
&= \sqrt{\left(\frac{4s}{4+s^2}-\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-8}{4+s^2}+\frac{8}{4+t^2}\right)^2}\end{align*} $$
then
$b=c=1$
since this is the radius

so 
 \begin{align*}A & =\arccos\left(\frac{a^2-b^2-c^2}{-2bc} \right) \\
& = \arccos\left(\frac{\left(\frac{4s}{4+s^2}-\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-8}{4+s^2}+\frac{8}{4+t^2}\right)^2-2}{-2} \right)\end{align*}
Which , since our radius is 1, only needs to be put in absolut value bars to obtain the arc-length metric (i.e from above $|arc-length|=|A\times 1|$). That is 
$$d(s,t)= \left|\arccos\left(\frac{\left(\frac{4s}{4+s^2}-\frac{4t}{4+t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-8}{4+s^2}+\frac{8}{4+t^2}\right)^2-2}{-2} \right)\right|$$
Too check this is a metric:

$d(s,s)=arccos(1)=0$

$d(s,t)=d(t,s)$ due to the fact that one can factor a $-1$ from the square expression.

So the question is if the triangle inequality holds. But I am getting stuck at what to do with the fact that certain points (the negative part of $\mathbb{R}$) is mapped to the left of the circle and the others on the right. Perhaps it is an obvious triangle inequality due to $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$? Any help or tips is greatly appreciated!

PS. This question came up when discussing metrics which are not norms, where only the discrete metric came to mind.

Pictures: 
M=middle point and all other letters correspond to the variables above. A=angle
[image]

example of lines and their corresponding intersection with the circle. the purple line intersects the x axis at 1.25 and the light blue at 1.8182
[image]

Comment: The point corresponding to the real number $t$ is the intersection of the circle and the line of equation $y = \frac{-2}{t}x + 2$ that isn't on the $y$-axis. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Who are $a,b,c,A$ please?

Comment: @OlivierRoche to your first question: yes, to the second : It is the cosine formula, I think it is called, $a$ is the length of the side opposite to the angle $A$ which is placed in the centre of the circle (the distance formula for the two points are used to obtain $a$) , $b$ and $c$ are the other sides of triangle which are respectively $1$ as they correspond to the radius of the circle.  I will try add a picture!

Comment: I did not check your computations but appears that you define a 2-point invariant on ${\mathbb R}$ using the formula   $d(s,t)= \angle(p^{-1}(s), p^{-1}(t))$ where $p$ is the stereographic projection from the unit circle (minus the point $(0,2)$) to the real line. But then the triangle inequality for $d$ is immediate from the triangle inequality on the circle (with respect to the arc-length metric). Are you having hard time verifying the latter? The fact that you decided to omit the point $(0,2)$ from the domain of $p$ (usually, it is mapped to the point called "infinity") is irrelevant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes! I am having trouble on how to verify the triangle inequality on the circle (under this arclength metric defined by arccos towards the end)

Comment: Then use the fact that if an arc $a$ is a union of two subarcs $b, c$ then the length of $a$ is the sum of the lengths of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Of course, verifying this by trigonometry would be insane, you should go back to the notion of angle in Euclidean geometry or arc-length in vector calculus.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I solved it, I want to thank you for sparking the idéa! thanks!